# What should I fill the gap between my siding and the concrete with?

Tags: outdoor

Back porch had a wooden deck that was rotting. After removal I know have a 5" gap between the bottom of my siding and the concrete the deck was on. The concrete isn't perfect but good enough shape that I am not planning on installing a new deck

I am having trouble figuring out a solution to fill the gap. At the door is easy, I can just put a step. But since the gap spans to the left and right of the door about 8' each direction I feel continuing the step the whole way might look very odd.

[image: drawing of issue]

Comment: pressure treated wood plank

Comment: A real picture might allow us to see better, but off hand something like flower/vegetable/pot(if legal there) boxes

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply extend the siding?  Can't find a match?

Answer (score 1):

Cover the concrete with decorative tile?  (exterior grade).

There are a lot of options and colors.